# Redirect with higher verbosity

Tags: message

Is it possible to redirect messages(`:messages`) to file (as I do now), just with higher verbosity than the verbosity level of the displayed messages?

The intention is that it would be the constant setting to be able to debug better unexpected errors

I mean for example: All messages of level 5 or less would be written to log file and displayed to user. All messages of level 20 or less would be just written to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:h :verbose](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Averbose) to do this.

Assume we use a `Less` command to capture `vim` output, we can see what `set filetype` really do like this:

```
Less 20verbose set filetype=cpp
```

The `20` is used to specify `'verbose'` for the sub command.

The `Less` command:

```
com -nargs=+ -complete=command Less call <sid>less(<q-args>, <q-mods>)

function s:less(cmd, mods)
  let winid = win_getid()
  exe a:mods 'new'
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile nobuflisted modifiable
  exe printf('put! =win_execute(%d, %s)', winid, string(a:cmd))
  1
endfunction
```

**update**

If you don't have `win_execute`, you can replace it with:

```
  " get outout in original window
  let output = execute(some_command)

  " split
  ... new
  ...

  " paste
  put! =output
```

Comment: Not what I thought about, but nice solution! I thought about  permanent arrangement that some messages are displayed and other are logged.

Comment: @eyalkarni Too vague, can't help without a very specific example.

Comment: I work in neovim win_execute doesn't work.

Comment: @eyalkarni see update.